# I want to find a specific answer

Tags: support, search

The answer was on this site or on [Ask Ubuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/). It explained use of su, sudo and what root account means. It had lots of pictures, one of which is this one: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y764L.png.

How do I go about searching for the answer?

Comment: Related: http://xkcd.com/149/ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FY764L.png)? You can use the [Stack Exchange network search](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FY764L.png) as well, although that's just a frontend for Google. The per-site search doesn't support looking up an image by URL

It was [How to NOT become a root user? Are administrators root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245201/how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root), on AU

Comment: Michael Mrozek♦, thank you for the excellent answer! I had tried the search box in upper right, and when nothing came out, decided that Google would be useless. Wrong.